# CodeMirror keeps appending when language dropdown is selected

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, codemirror

I am using CodeMirror to provie syntax highlighting for a little project to save programming departments code bits.
The asp-mvc page consists of a textxt, a dropdown list for languages, a textbox for a description and a textbox for code.
when the user makes his/her first selection from the dropdown, a nice Codemirror editor is created. If they were to make change the language selection, a NEW CodeMirror box is created and pre-pended above the first box. this goes on each time a selection is made, causing the boxes to stack and become confusing. I would like a single Codemirror editor at all times. If they were to type in text, for instance, then decide to choose languages, the text should just be copied over to a new CodeMirror editor.
Here is a description of how to do this in the [manual](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html):

> In cases where you don't want to append the editor to an element, and need more control over the way it is inserted, the first argument
>   to the CodeMirror function can also be a function that, when given a
>   DOM element, inserts it into the document somewhere. This could be
>   used to, for example, replace a textarea with a real editor:
>
> var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror(function(elt) {
>   myTextArea.parentNode.replaceChild(elt, myTextArea); }, {value:
>   myTextArea.value}); However, for this use case, which is a common way
>   to use CodeMirror, the library provides a much more powerful shortcut:
>
> var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(myTextArea); This will,
>   among other things, ensure that the textarea's value is updated with
>   the editor's contents when the form (if it is part of a form) is
>   submitted.

as you will see in my code, I am using the second method, but to no avail. Heres the markup and JavaScript:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new {id="CodeBlock"}))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title, new { type = "Search", autofocus = "true", id = "title", placeholder = "Code snip Title", style = "width: 200px", @maxlength = "50" })
    @Html.DropDownList("Language",
    new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(LangType))),
    "Select Language", new {id="codeDDl", @onchange = "changeSyntax()" })
    <p></p>
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Description, new { type = "Search", autofocus = "true", id = "description", placeholder = "Code snip Description",style = "Width: 800px" })
    <p></p>
    <div id="CodeArea">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Code, new {id = "code", style = "width: 800px"})
    </div>
    <p></p>


    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="Reset()"/>




}
<script>
    var cm;
    function changeSyntax() {
        switch (document.getElementById("codeDDl").selectedIndex) {

        case 1:                 
            BuildBox(true, true, "text/x-csharp");  
            break;
        case 2:
            BuildBox(true, true, "text/x-css");
            break;
        case 3:
            BuildBox(true, true, "text/x-chtml");
            break;
        case 4:
            BuildBox(true, true, "text/x-javascript");
            break;
        case 5:
            BuildBox(true, true, "text/x-perl");
            break;
        case 6:
            BuildBox(true, true, "text/x-php");
            break;
        case 7:
            BuildBox(true, true, "text/x-python");
            break;
        case 8:
            BuildBox(true, true, "text/x-ruby");
            break;
        case 9:
            BuildBox(true, true, "text/x-sql");
            break;
        case 10:
            BuildBox(true, true, "text/x-vb");
            break;
        case 11:
            BuildBox(true, true, "text/x-xml");
            break;
        }
    }

    function BuildBox(lines, match, mode) {

        cm = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"),
        {
            lineNumbers: lines,
            matchBrackets: match,
            mode: mode
        });


    }

    function Reset() {
        cm.toTextArea();
        document.getElementById("code").value = "";
        document.getElementById("codeDDl").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("codeDDl").selectedIndex = 0;
    }
```

The model is simple and can be derived from the Razor controls, controller does nothing special at this time.
Any ideas out there on how I can accomplish having a single CodeMirror Editor appear no matter how many time the language selection box is changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to call fromTextArea *ONCE* ever (per text area).

So create it, store it off, and use it if you need to change anything later.

```
var cmInstance = $('#code').data('CodeMirrorInstance');

if (!cmInstance)
{
    cmInstance = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"),
    {
        lineNumbers: lines,
        matchBrackets: match,
        mode: mode
    });
    $('#code').data('CodeMirrorInstance', cmInstance);
}



//later
var cm = $('#code').data('CodeMirrorInstance');
cm.whateverYouWantToDoToCodeMirror();
```