# Programming language select droptown Codemirror

Tags: javascript, editor, codemirror

I would like to have a language selecting dropdown for [codemirror.](http://codemirror.net)
I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39167641/codemirror-keeps-appending-when-language-dropdown-is-selected) but i cant make heads or tails of it. Could anyone clear it up for me or provide a solution? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make an object `{'go':'text/x-go','javascript':'text/javascript'}` and so on and index it.

```js
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('edit'),{lineNumbers:true,mode:'text/x-go'});
function select(x) {
var optionText = x.options[x.selectedIndex].innerText;
var modes = {'Golang':'text/x-go','Javascript':'text/javascript','Css':'text/css'};

editor.setOption('mode', modes[optionText]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.38.0/codemirror.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.38.0/codemirror.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.38.0/mode/javascript/javascript.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.38.0/mode/go/go.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.38.0/mode/css/css.min.js"></script>

<select onchange="select(this)">
<option>Golang</option>
<option>Javascript</option>
<option>Css</option>
</select> <br> 
<textarea id="edit">
//Try do package main and change modes
</textarea>
```

Comment: When I run this with google chrome as a html file it shows weird things next to the cursor

Comment: I know but it is CDN-dependent